# Dodging a moral, metaphysical or otherwise abstract question by answering the mechanics of the situation

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

The example that made me wonder if there's a word for this is that my bandmate can't enter the building where our rehearsal space is located on his own anymore, because the landlord took down the old keycard system and installed an app-based one instead that you need a rather new phone to run properly, which some of the tenants don't have, and don't want to spend money on.

When my friend expressed his frustrations to the landlord, he said that there was no solution to this problem and started explaining the mechanics behind the app not working on his phone.

Is there a word for this diversionary tactic?

Comment: What's the dodge?

Comment: It's related to "disingenuousness" in that someone is deliberately misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Anyhow it's complicated because in the end, every abstract meets the concrete in a real situation.

Comment: An example would help.

Comment: '**Ignoratio elenchi**' (irrelevant conclusion, missing the point) – an argument that may in itself be valid, but does not address the issue in question. [[Wikipedia _ list of fallacies / false arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies)]

Comment: The example offered does not exactly involve a 'metaphysical or otherwise abstract question'. It does involve a moral and a legal question, but they are not particularly abstract.

Comment: What's the problem with the answer? "I can't get in." "You're right, you can't. Not unless you get a new phone." That's a perfectly good answer—just not one that's welcome.